# How can I bound an associated type to work with the `?` operator?

Tags: error-handling, rust, associated-types

Given the following Rust:

```rust
struct E;

trait Fallible {
    type Error: Into<E>;
    fn e(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}

fn test(f: &impl Fallible) -> Result<(), E> {
    Ok(f.e()?)
}
```

I am trying to express that the `Fallible::Error` type can be converted to an `E` and therefore should be usable with the `?` operator. But, for some reason the `?` is based on the `From` trait, which I'm not sure that it is possible to bound.

This currently fails with:

```
error[E0277]: `?` couldn't convert the error to `E`
 --> src/lib.rs:9:13
  |
9 |     Ok(f.e()?)
  |             ^ the trait `std::convert::From<<impl Fallible as Fallible>::Error>` is not implemented for `E`
  |
  = note: the question mark operation (`?`) implicitly performs a conversion on the error value using the `From` trait
  = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you cannot bind at the trait level [yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/44265), you can do so on the function:

```rust
struct E;

trait Fallible {
    type Error: Into<E>;
    fn e(&self) -> Result<(), Self::Error>;
}

fn test<T>(f: &T) -> Result<(), E>
where
    T: Faillible,
    E: From<T::Error>,
{
    Ok(f.e()?)
}
```

Comment: I'm not so sure about the claim that GATs are going to help with this issue. Could you provide clarification there?

Comment: @That3Percent if you [try `type Error where E: From<Self::Error>;`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=29ee7b119d0dc145344f00ca51089e26), you'll get an error "where clauses on associated types are unstable" with a link to the GAT issue.